# Busquedas en arrays MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Buenas, llevo un par de días buscando informacion para poder hacer esta busqueda

> Buscar los libros escritos por 2 autores

Os paso captura de como esta almacenado en mi MongoDB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me hago a la idea que "author" es un array y ha de haber alguna forma posible de decirle a la sentencia `find` `"author".count() = 2`

Pero no encuentro nada...

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador [`all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) para obtener los documentos que incluyan **todos los elementos** del array.

> Selecciona los documentos **siempre y cuando** el campo en cuestión **tenga todos los valores** del array.

```
db.collections.books.find({
  author: {
    $all: [ 'author1', 'author2']
  }
});
```

Si usas [`mongoose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose):

```
Book.find({
  author: {
    $all: [ 'author1', 'author2']
  }
});
```

---

**Actualización**

> yo quiero que me muestre los libros escritos por 2 autores (que el array autor contenga 2 registros)

En ese caso puedes añadir el operador [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) para:

- El array contenga los autores a coincidir
- El array contenga un tamaño de la cantidad de autores

Ejemplo:

```
Book.find({
  author: {
    $all: [ 'author1', 'author2'],
    $size: 2
  }
});
```

Lo anterior se traduce a: *"Encuentra todos los libros que sean escritos solo por X y Y autor"*.

Comment: hola @guzgarcia me temo que esta no seria la sentencia. Muchas gracias por la ayuda porque me servira para otros casos. Pero yo quiero que me muestre los libros escritos por 2 autores (que el array autor contenga 2 registros)

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @guzgarcia.  te dejo la sentencia que me ha servico!!! (pero utilizando tu respuesta) db.books.find({author: {$size: 2}});